# Can not compile google test with MinGW on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, googletest

I tried to compile google test framework with MinGW on Windows following instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248237/how-to-compile-googletest-on-windows-using-mingw-with-msys), but I got errors when executing `make`:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
In file included from d:/downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:45:0:
D:/downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc: In static member function 'static void testing::internal::ThreadLocalRegistryImpl::StartWatcherThreadFor(DWORD)':
D:/downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:495:21: error: '::OpenThread' has not been declared
     HANDLE thread = ::OpenThread(SYNCHRONIZE | THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION,
                     ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help. I tried:

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" --with-pthreads=no
```

But got:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "D:/downloads/googletest-master/googletest/--with-pthreads=no" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" --with-pthreads=no
```

I don't think `--with-pthreads=no` is a valid cmake option. CMake tries to interpret it as the source directory. Remove that option. I think google test needs pthreads anyways, that is why `OpenThread` is not declared, because it depends on `pthreads`.

If you're not using the MSYS shell, try to use the "MinGW Makefiles" generator for cmake.

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Then run `make`.